# React Native - how can I pass a function to a stack screen in a navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this navigator with different screens inside a modal. To close the modal, a button needs to be pressed to activate a setState function. The problem now is that the button to close the entire modal is inside one of the stack screens. Please how can I pass the function down as a prop from the parent to the screen. Below is a summary of my code. Thanks.

//Parent.js

```
    const [state, setState] = useState(false)
            <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Screen1"
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}
             setState={setState}
            >
                <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
```

//Screen1.js

```
export default Screen1 = ({setState})=>{
  return (
   <View>
      <Button title={Press me} onPress={()=>{
        setState(false)}} />
   </view>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass it as the initial param like below

```
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    initialParams={{ setState: setState }}
  />
```

And access it like below

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="setState"
        onPress={() => route.params.setState(false)}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

But for complex scenarios better consider a context based implementation.

Comment: Isn't the `initialParams={{ setState: setState }}` be `initialParams={{ setState: state}}` ? I'm not sure. Just feel a little bit wired.

Comment: didnt work when i passed like that, just like style props this also expects an object i guess

Comment: Thanks @GuruparanGiritharan. It seems to work but I am getting a yellow sign warning that "non serializable values were found in the navigation state..". Could there be a better way to handle this or I should ignore the warning?

Comment: That happens when you pass function as params, there is no solution as of now https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6827.